# Add a css class to a taxonomy permalink

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy, html

I need to add a css class to every `<a>` element retrieved by `the_terms()` (or similar function) in order to open the taxonomy permalink in a fancybox modal window.
I've been searching this whole afternoon for a Filter that could handle it, with no success.

Anyway, I got into this (poor) solution below:

```
$cities = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'cities');           

        foreach ($cities as $city) {
            echo '<a class="fancybox" href="'. get_term_link( $city->slug, 'cities' ).'">'.$city->name. '</a>' ;
        }
```

But it's too 'ugly' to put in a template file.

Is there any wordpress filter that deals with this question of permalink html generation?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter you are looking for is `term_links-$taxonomy`, where `$taxonomy` is the taxonomy name. This will filter the `$term_links` links array before outputting by `the_terms()`:

```
add_filter('term_links-cities', 'ad_filter_links');

function ad_filter_links($term_links) {
    foreach ($term_links as $term_link) {
        $term_link = str_replace('<a ', '<a class="fancybox"', $term_link);
    }
    return $term_links;
}
```

Comment: whoah! that's what i'm looking for. Thanks you very much!

By the way, how did you search this hook? I spent hours on google with no success in finding a similar suggestion

Comment: @SusanSiqueira you are welcome. I rely on the source code to find hooks, this one from `get_the_term_list()` function used by `the_terms()` which both are located in `wp-includes/category-template.php`.

Comment: aaaa I looked up the code and found the hook. now I'm beginning to understand how filter works. thanks again!